# How to dumb logs from Azure through Python also how to get all user Sessions form Azure Portal through Python

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I want to dumb out all logs of the user and record their session time in his Azure Portal through Python. Please Suggest me Python libraries to play with Azure Portal

Comment: You can refer to [azure-sdk-for-python/azure-mgmt-portal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/portal/azure-mgmt-portal), [Python API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/?term=portal) and [Provision and manage Azure resources with management libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-overview#provision-and-manage-azure-resources-with-management-libraries)